# Merge sort variation n+m, confused

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Let `A` be an array of `n` integers already sorted in ascending order.
Let `B` be array of `m` integers that are not sorted.
We know that the set of integers in `A` is disjoint with the set of integers in `B`. Describe an algorithm to produce an array where all the `n + m` integers have been sorted in ascending order. Your algorithm should terminate in `O(n + m log m)` time.

I know this should be something like merge sort, but the `n+m` in the `O(n+mlogm)` throws me off. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should sort the B array first: `O(mlogm)`
After that you have two sorted arrays and you need to merge them, this will take: `O(n+m)`
Now the whole process is `O(mlogm + (n+m) )` which is equal to `O(mlogm)`.

Comment: If we don't know the relation between `n` and `m`, then I guess the total complexity should actually be `O(mlogm+n)`.